# How to replicate PHP serialized and Base64Encoded string in C# .NET

Tags: c#, php, .net, serialization

Consider this code in PHP:

```
$myObj = "<test>";
$value = base64_encode(serialize($myObj));
print_r ($value)
```

`Result`: czo2OiI8dGVzdD4iOw==

In .NET I have tried this:

```
var toSerialize = "<test>";
var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toSerialize);
var encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
```

`Result`: PHRlc3Q+

Using .NET, how do I get the same `czo2OiI8dGVzdD4iOw==` result that I got in PHP? Is this possible?

Comment: `serialize($myObj)` returns  `s:6:"<test>";` So,  `Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("s:6:\"<test>\";"))` returns the base64 string you expected...

Answer (score 0):

Why even have the serialize()/System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes() call if what you're encoding is already a string? Just encode that string itself, i.e.

```
$myObj = "<test>";
$value = base64_encode($myObj);
```

or in C#

```
var myObj = "<test>";
var value = Convert.ToBase64String(myObj);
```

If what you're REALLY trying to encode is an "object" (as in, a set of properties and their values), and not a string, then you need to first turn the object into the same sort of string... e.g. a JSON string.

For PHP, it's as simple as [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode). For .NET... see [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/json-serialization) for example.

Comment: I was using string "<test>" to make things simple and to illustrate that the results are different. I will be encoding an `object.`  I agree that storing JSON would be best, but we are trying to port an existing PHP job into .NET.

Comment: @duyn9uyen  `I agree that storing JSON would be best, but we are trying to port an existing PHP job into .NET` So what is the problem with Json when there is no .Net equivalent of `serialize($myObj)`

Comment: Maybe the answer is that it is not possible because there is no .NET equivalent method to PHP's `serialize()`.

Comment: @duyn9uyen  `Maybe the answer is that it is not possible because there is no .NET equivalent method to PHP's serialize()` It is also not correct. A c# deserializer compatible with php can be written (if it is not already  written by now).

Comment: Well fine... If you *have* to use an equivalent of PHP's serialize(), use a custom equivalent (since there's no built in one). Here's one: https://sourceforge.net/projects/csphpserial/

Although IMHO, since you're rewriting anyway, NOW would be the perfect time to switch to a more universal and stable format, like JSON. Consumers of your data can be easily adjusted to use JSON instead of their unserliaze() equivalent.

Comment: @boen_robot, thanks for the link.  And you're right. I will push to use Json since it is universal.  Thanks again.